# How to create a custom dialog box in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I have a button. When I clicked that button I want a dialog box to popup with multiple text field and button. I have been looking all around to try to figure out how to do this but I keep on getting more confused. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example of a dialog box is this. Make a new substack of your mainstack and call the substack "Dialog". Add a button to the substack, call the button "OK" and give it the following script:

```
on mouseUp
  set the dialogData to "OK" 
  close this stack
end mouseUp
```

Make another button in your mainstack and give it this script:

```
on mouseUp
  go stack "Dialog" as modal
  put the dialogData
end mouseUp
```

You now have a dialog window. You can add fields and more buttons to your Dialog stack. For example, you can create a cancel button with the following script:

```
on mouseUp
  set the dialogData to "Cancel"
  close this stack
end mouseUp
```

and if you have a field, you can change the script of button "OK" into

```
on mouseUp
  set the dialogData to fld 1
  close this stack
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new substack in your file that looks like you want the dialog to look, then use the "modal" command to show it.

Though modal dialogs are a bit old-fashioned, so why not just make it a separate stack, open that (e.g. using the "modeless" command) and that way let the user check back or copy data from the main window?

**Update:** Do what Mark suggests. The "as modal" syntax is more readable than just using "modal" as a command (wasn't aware LiveCode had that variant now). However, I'd still suggest using modeless if you at all can, it just is nicer to your users if they can go back and forth between windows instead of being forced into a fixed order by you.